# Выбор каждые n записей по результату

Tags: sql, oracle

Столкнулся с проблемой выбора `n`-ого количества записей. Поясню:
нужно выбрать 10 строк по каждому результату в таблице. 
Можно, конечно, воспользоваться `Union`, но результатов около 1000.

```
select * from t_1 x where x.result = '1' and rownum <= 10 
union 
select * from t_1 x where x.result = '2' and rownum <= 10 
union 
select * from t_1 x where x.result = '3' and rownum <= 10 
union 
select * from t_1 x where x.result = '4' and rownum <= 10
```

Вопрос, как написать без Union? Поле Result имеет около 1000 уникальных значений.

Comment: Примеры таблиц, кода? Где проблема? Что у Вас не получилось?

Comment: select * from t_1 x
where x.result = '1'
and rownum <= 10
union
select * from t_1 x
where x.result = '2'
and rownum <= 10
union
select * from t_1 x
where x.result = '3'
and rownum <= 10
union
select * from t_1 x
where x.result = '4'
and rownum <= 10

Comment: Вопрос, как написать без Union? Поле Result имеет около 1000 уникальных значений.

Comment: А значения что ли нет в каком порядке записи, т.е. первых попавшихся 10 шт на группу. И пожалуйста приводите уточнения в тексте вопроса (ссылка править под вопросом), а не в комментариях

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select *
  from (
    select A.*, row_number() over(partition by result order by null) RN
      from table A
  )
 where RN<=10
```

В предложении `order by` вместо `null` стоит указать правильный порядок сортировки для определения какие же 10 записей из набора показывать

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно. Извиняюсь за кривой вопрос)