# Выборка из таблицы, где определенное значение будет повторяться не более заданного количество раз

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задача на MS SQL. Имеется таблица Table с уникальным Id и неуникальными значениями в поле Value:

|ID   | Value  |
|1    | 155    |
|2    | 155    |
|3    | 182    |
|4    | 182    |
|5    | 182    |
|6    | 182    |
|7    | 182    |
|8    | 137    |
|9    | 147    |

--Здесь значение 182 повторяется 5 раз

Как организовать такую выборку,  в которой бы определенное значение поля Value будет повторяться не более заданного количества раз.

Например, если мы задаем, чтобы значение 182 в поле Value повторялось не более 2х раз, то выборка должна получиться следующего вида:

|ID   | Value  |
|1    | 155    |
|2    | 155    |
|3    | 182    |
|4    | 182    |
|8    | 137    |
|9    | 147    |

--Здесь значение 182 повторяется только 2 раза.

Нужно написать "Select * from Table" где будет работать такое условие. Думаю, что здесь нужно использовать COUNT и GROUP BY, но у меня не получается написать такое условие...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выбор каждые n записей по результату](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612485/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b5-n-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
select id, value from
(select id, value, 
row_number() over(partition by value order by id) as nrank 
from Table
where value in ('182')
) t
where nrank <= 2
union
select * from Table where value not in ('182')
```

Второй вариант без union по подсказе teran:

```
select id, value from
(select id, value, 
row_number() over(partition by value order by id) as nrank 
from Table
) t
where (value in ('182') and nrank <= 2) or value not in ('182')
```

Comment: Подставляю вместо Value '182' получаю выборку только из двух строк, где value =155. Не получилось выбрать  то, что требуется, с таким условием.

Comment: Т.е. получается два запроса объединить в один нужно? если Value in ('182'), то только первые 2 строки, во всех остальных случаях - все строки? Поменял запрос.

Comment: Строки, где  Value NOT IN ('182') выводим как обычно. Строки, где  Value IN ('182') выводим не более заданного количество раз, например не более 2-х раз. Итоговая выборка, которая должна получиться, написана в конце вопроса.

Comment: Пробуйте тот запрос, что я переписал, он должен вернуть то, что вам нужно :)

Comment: Не знаю, без Union мне только всякие извращения с case видятся. да и что мешает в дальнейшем обращаться к результату этой выборки, обернув ее в select value from (результат выборки из первой таблицы) x?

Comment: В принципе, это прекрасно работает. А нельзя как нибудь без Union? Потому как далее, этот запрос мне нужно будет вложить во внутрь другой выборки SELECT * From Table2 where Id IN ( полученные Id из этой выборки первой таблицы)

Comment: почему же, `where value = 182 and rank <= 2 or value != 182`

Comment: @teran ну да, или так тоже, кстати :)

Comment: @KadafiVSC, проверил, даже если этот запрос с Union вложить в другой, все прекрасно работает. Вопрос снят, большое спасибо за решение!:)

Comment: @teran тоже спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 0):

Если надо выбрать только неповторяющиеся значения поля [Field] таблицы [Table], то

```
SELECT [Field] FROM [Table] GROUP BY [Field] HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

А вообще я посоветовал бы познакомиться с [ранжирующиими функциями.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, к сожалению. А так, проблем с работой GROUP by и COUNT  у меня нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    ID      INT,
    Value   INT
)

INSERT @Test
VALUES
    (1, 155),
    (2, 155),
    (3, 182),
    (4, 182),
    (5, 182),
    (6, 182),
    (7, 182),
    (8, 137),
    (9, 147)

DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @Value INT = 182

SELECT t.*
FROM @Test t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (@Count) ID
    FROM @Test
    WHERE Value = t.Value 
        AND Value = @Value
    ORDER BY t.ID
    ) i
WHERE t.ID = i.ID
    OR Value != @Value
```

Comment: там не все значения нужны по 2 штуки, а только для 182, остальные без изменений

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, исправил