# Выгрузить по 2 записи из связанной таблицы

Tags: mysql

Только mysql

```
CREATE TABLE main
(
    id         INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title      VARCHAR(255)            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sub
(
    id         INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title      VARCHAR(255)            NOT NULL,
    parent_id INT UNSIGNED
);
```

Один ко многим. Цель: выгрузить все записи основной таблицы и по две связанных записи (`LIMIT 2`) из подтаблицы (`main.id = sub.parent_id`)
Как это сделать?

Предполагаю, что-то вроде

```
SELECT * FROM main JOIN (SELECT * FROM sub WHERE sub.parent_id = main.id LIMIT 2)
```

но это, понятно, не работает

Comment: Версия сервера какая? По какому принципу выбирать 2 связанные записи из всех возможных? Что делать, если по этому критерию 2 и 3 записи неразличимы?

Comment: Версия сервера: 10.1.28-MariaDB; 
Принцип? main.id = sub.parent_id, ORDER BY rand(). В общем две любых записи. 
То есть в итоге должно получится:
    Строка 1: Все поля записи 1 таблицы main, Все поля связанной записи таблицы sub
    Cтрока 2: Все поля записи 1 таблицы main, Все поля связанной записи таблицы sub
    Строка 3: Все поля записи 2 таблицы main, Все поля связанной записи таблицы sub
    Строка 4: Все поля записи 2 таблицы main, Все поля связанной записи таблицы sub
    Строка 5: Все поля записи 3 таблицы main, Все поля связанной записи таблицы sub
и т.д.

Comment: Ну она и CTE знает, и ROW_NUMBER()... вообще никаких проблем быть не должно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612495/194569

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612495/194569 - это для Oracle