# Выборка последних по дате изменения уникальных записей PostgreSQL/RoR

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Имеется необходимость в запросе, который будет возвращать от модели 2 поля post и  role. Подстрока для поиска приходит с фронта, записи с вхождением этой подстроки отсеять по уникальности и вернуть последнее по дате изменения. Реально ли это всё осуществить в пределах одного запроса?
Пример [записей в гугл-таблицах](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fYHk5iwPRN94pNvxU3OejsfDNjUf3CqYONDe-jhzQKY/edit?usp=sharing)

То есть при вхождении подстроки "начальник 1" вернуть должно 4 и 5 записи
При вхождении "ачаль" вернуть 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 13 записи

Пробовал покурить вложенные запросы SELECT но моих познаний пока не хватает для построения рабочих конструкций.

Comment: Не очень хорошо выносить часть вопроса за пределы ресурса, если гугл-таблица исчезнет, вопрос станет не доступен для анализа и поиска.

Comment: Примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612495/194569 только like / ilike добавить в where внутреннего запроса что бы получить только нужные записи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут не нужен вложенный запрос, можно воспользоваться `DISTINCT ON` вместе с `ORDER`, чтобы получить уникальные записи

```
Model.select("DISTINCT ON(models.post) models.id, models.post, models.role")
     .where('models.post ILIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%").order(updated_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил пару моментов, вроде как работает. Будем тестировать)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Если ответ решил вашу проблему, примите его пожалуйста