# 10 предыдущих строчек и 10 последующих

Tags: mysql, sql

Задача в том, чтобы вытащить 10 предыдущих и последующих строчек из таблицы.
Каким образом это возможно выполнить?

Знаем не id записи, а скажем url (alt_title)

LIMIT в целом на 20 строчек

Comment: например union из двух запросов, первый берет лимитом 10 строк меньших данной с сортировкой в обратном порядке (по тому полю от которого отсчет ведете), второй соответственно 10 строк больших (либо равных) в возрастающем порядке

Comment: А если MySQL 8 версии, то можно пронумеровать с помощью row_number() и взять нужные номера

Comment: Возможно что то напутал, посмотрел версию MySQL "10.3.27-MariaDB".  Можно пожалуйста пример с row_number

Comment: Maria 10.3 это mysql 5.7 согласно информации с сайта mariaDB

Comment: Пример row_number на всякий случай. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612495/194569 только конечно его надо конкретно доработать, что бы считать строки с правильного места, а скорее брать нумерацию в двух направлениях. А вообще поиск по row_number дает предостаточно примеров начиная с документации с которой и надо начинать